# setting scroll position to a particular row of primefaces datatable with performance

Tags: performance, primefaces, datatable

I have a data table with thousands of data. i have a search functionality. if I search a term, the row which contains the term has to be highlighted and scroll position should be on the row. it is working fine. but it takes too much of time to position the scrollbar. this leads to performance issue. can anyone help to fix this.

currently i have set style class to the match row. searching for the style class and calculating the position and setting it with jQuery.

```js
var trElement = $("tr.found").first();
            var trParentElement = trElement.parent();
            var childTop = trElement.offset().top;
            var parentTop = trParentElement.offset().top;
            var scrollPos = childTop - parentTop;
            $('#table').scrollTop(scrollPos);
```

is there any other way? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this a performance issue exactly, does it take seconds to scroll somehow?

Comment: yes it takes 6 to 9 seconds to scroll to the position. data volume is nearly 400 records.

Comment: The performance issue here is likely loading thousands of rows to the client. This adds up really fast for non-trivial tables. Better rethink this UI, e.g. show 20-40 rows with pagination, add server-side filters etc...